# Writing unique character-based dialogue?

Tags: dialogue, word-choice, videogame

I have read this on many sites and articles: "When writing dialogue, you should give every character their own unique dialogue so that it would be recognizable without writing their names."

But none of them have mentioned, "how?". So I thought asking here would be best.

Does it mean using certain words for each character? (i.e. one who uses German words sometimes?) Or does it mean something entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the question is like answering how you ride a bicycle: You simply "know" how to do it. And if you can't do... then like with a bicycle you try. In the case of writing characters, each character has some story to tell, internal motivations, internal feelings. This is the case for virtually any character, in any video game, short story, screenplay, novel etc., and from this *character*, you can infer what they *would* say, if they *were* such a person.

The possibilities of constructing good dialogue are virtually endless:

- average sentence length
- merging of languages
- swearing
- choice of jargon (for a professional perhaps)
- volume of delivery
- sex/gender point of view of the character saying the dialogue
- intelligence of the content
- ...

In writing dialogue, in a way, you need make all of these decisions at the same time. This is *how*.

However, the skill of "knowing how", is a trainable one. Writing good dialogue requires you to listen to how people speak, and what they say, and how you think of them as a result. Read many dialogues, talk to many people. In time, it will give you a more intuitive feel for what dialogue to write. Either way, expect to rewrite dialogues and redefine characters, because writing good dialogue (or writing any good text for that matter) is difficult, even for professional writers.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer. So it's basically a matter of experience for writing good dialogues that suit each character. And by reading this, I just came up with another important thing to share for those who have the same question: In video games, unlike books, dialogues' speed would be important too.